# nvim-typescript wrongly complains about non-existent type

Tags: javascript, typescript, vim, neovim

I'm trying to use `neovim` with the following minimal configuration:

```
call plug#begin()

Plug 'mhartington/nvim-typescript', {'do': './install.sh'}
Plug 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'

Plug 'HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim'
Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }
Plug 'Shougo/denite.nvim'

call plug#end()
```

In a `nodejs` project, I installed `pg` and `@types/pg`:

```
npm i pg; npm i -D @types/pg;
```

Then in a `.ts` file, I'm importing from `pg`:

```
import * as pg from 'pg';
```

yet I get the following error from this line:

```
const queryLogger = (queryRes: QueryResult<object>): string => ...
> 2304: Cannot find name 'QueryResult'.
```

but if I force an error as such, the type is clearly known as it references `QueryResult<T>`:

```
const { Pool } = pg;
const pool = new Pool();

pool.query(sql, params) as string;
> 2352: Conversion of type 'Promise<QueryResult<any>>' ...
```

even more strangely, building and running the code throws no errors - everything seems to work as expected, regardless of the error.

What is going on? Is there anything further I can do to debug the issue?

---

[`nvim-typescript` issue](https://github.com/mhartington/nvim-typescript/issues/271)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horribly simple answer - the type was `pg.QueryResult<T>`.